# C# Console-Application with no console but winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, console

We have an application that is a WinForms-Application. It accepts startup parameters and can perform certain jobs with no UI by using the command line.

Now, we also want some console-output, like for example when using `application.exe /help`.

The Issue we are now facing is: How to bring both worlds together in a "nice" way:

1. When setting the Output Type to "Windows Application",all the UI stuff works fine, but `Console.WriteLine()` doesn't show results when used from cmd.
2. When setting the Output Type to "Console", generally both things work, BUT: The Application (when used in UI-Mode so to say) raises a console window, that stays open until the application terminates.

Is there a way to bypass the visibility of the console-window?

In the real world, I can find applications using one of three approaches - but I don't like either of them:

1. Leave the console window open when running in UI-Mode, who cares?
2. Use `user32.dll` to hide the window (it still flashes, tho)
3. Use Windows-Application as Output-Type and show Console-Output as "message boxes", when used from the command line.

Comment: Instead of doing some mixed mode magic I hardly recommend making two applications. One console and one WinForms. The common logic can be stored in a class libary which both applications use.

Comment: There's another option: you can also create the console window manually if needed. Of course, that has its own can of worms. In the end, you have to make a choice that best suits your application; and keep in mind you can always access the console streams if your application happens to run in a console (e.g. someone runs it from cmd).

Comment: This is simple.  Create a console application.  Then in menu Project : Add new Item : WindowsForm.  You will start with a console application and then in the console you will need to put form1.ShowDialog.

Comment: @jdweng That's his second point. This does have the downside that the console window is also visible when you don't want it.

Comment: If you start your app with `application.exe /help`, `/help` is an argument, so in `Program.cs` you can check that an argument has been supplied (in `static void Main(string[] args)`, `args.Length > 0` ). In this case (if `args` contains `/help`), start a new Process that runs `cmd.exe`, redirect and write to its StandardInput your Help message and `WaitForExit()`. You can the decide whether to execute the UI or not (i.e., call `Application.Run(new SomeForm());` only if the CMD Prompt has not been shown).

Comment: Instead of using a console window create a 2nd form with just a text box and use the text box for the output.

Comment: Tweak around the app so that Console does something useful even when there shouldn't be a console windows sound weird. Shouldn't you not just use a distinct logging framework for this and just not do Console.Something directly? That gives you the option todo something more fitting in the UI case. I would call that then "nice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out a solution, thx to @Luaan s comment:

I'm now using the Output Type Windows Application (so, no console window) - but simply registering the Console with the Applications "Parent" Console.

This now behaves as expected:

- No console is shown during normal startup.
- When used from within an existing console window (ps / cmd) the output is printed, because that consoles are then technically the parent-console of the application.

  ```
  public class GUIConsoleWriter
  {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
    private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

    public static void RegisterGUIConsoleWriter()
    {
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    }
  }
  ```

And then, firstline in `Main()`:

```
  static void Main(String[] args)
  {
        GUIConsoleWriter.RegisterGUIConsoleWriter();
  }
```

Now, using regular `Console.WriteLine()` works. Ofc. this is limited to writing output, but for the scope of my projects that is sufficent, as input has to be provided with arguments, no interactive console-options.

When another application needs to fetch output programmatically, you ofc. can't do `myApp.exe /doSomething` but need to do `cmd /C myApp.exe /doSomething` because the application itself doesn't own a console.

AND you have to manually take care to "exit" your application, after providing output, otherwhise the process won't return.